# Exchange error 116/EXOLEDB

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, exchange, exchange-2003, email-server

Im getting the following error when starting up exchange:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: EXOLEDB
Event Category: Events 
Event ID: 116
Date:  12/9/2009
Time:  11:15:24 AM
User:  N/A
Computer: 
Description:
Microsoft Exchange OLEDB was unable to initialize event system correctly.  Support for store event may have been disabled. HRESULT = 0x8004010f.

For more information, click http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.
```

so a couple questions - is this a big deal?  the server appears to be working normally, and i havent noticed any unwanted behavior.

what do i need to do to fix it?  ive found a couple KB articles like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316622 with some instruction, and they seem potentially hazardous.  What would i be looking for WRT SystemMailbox{GUID}?  Ive found the systemattendant and smtp mailboxes, but not that one.

Exchange 2k3sp2, Server 2k3sp2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the error correspond with anything (restarting the server, moving a mailbox, accessing via OWA)? How often are you getting it?

Comment: it corresponds to restarting the Information Store service.  it only happens once at startup (or when the service is restarted).

Comment: I was just going to point you to KB 316622, but it looks like you've already found it.  If you are uncomfortable following the steps and your Exchange server is working fine for you, I would say this is a case of "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: any idea what i might be missing by not fixing this?  error reporting, etc?

Comment: I did a quick search of past cases with this error, and most of them were people calling in just because they saw this error in their event logs.  The two other problems I see are potentially trouble viewing messages in OWA, trouble moving mailboxes to a different Exchange Server, and Event Sinks (such as the auto accept agent) may not work.  It doesn't sound like you are seeing any of those problems, but if you want to resolve... open a support ticket with Microsoft support and they'll walk you through resolving: http://support.microsoft.com/ph/1773#tab6